# Matrix overloading

Tags: c++

I'm making a 2D dynamic Matrix class. Problem arises in my copy constructor and =operator. Kindly tell me what am I doing wrong. Here is the code: (The cout's are for checking.

```
private: 
int rows;
int coloumns;
float **ptr;

Matrix(const Matrix & M)
{     cout << "copy const called"<<endl;

    cout << "1 "<< endl;
    if(rows < 0 || column < 0)  // To check if its a garbage value or not
    {
        rows = 0, col = 0;
        ptr = NULL;
        cout << "2 "<< endl;
    }

    else if(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout << "3 "<< endl;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < col; i++)
        {
            delete [] ptr[i];
        }
        cout << "4 "<< endl;
        delete [] ptr;
        ptr = NULL;
        cout << "5 "<< endl;
    }
    cout << "6 "<< endl;

    *this = M;
    cout << "7 "<< endl;
}           
Matrix operator= (const Matrix &M)
{
    if(this == &M)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    if(row!=0 && columns != 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < columns; i++)
        {
            delete [] ptr[i];
        }
        delete [] ptr;
        ptr = NULL;
    }
    rows = M.rows; col = M.columns;

        ptr = new float *[rows];
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = new float [col];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i< rows ; i++)
        {
            for( int j=0 ; j< columns ;j++)
            {
                ptr[i][j] = M.ptr[i][j];
            }
        }

    return *this;
}
 int main()
 {
   Matrix M1(2,3);
   Matrix M2(M1);
   M2(0, 0) = 1;
 }
```

It stops at the " *this = M " in the copy constructor. Moreover, I wanted to confirm that when I return something in the = operator, does it take the place of the whole " *this = M" , or just replaces M?

Note: 
Not allowed to use vectors.

Comment: "Problem arises" isn't very descriptive. What problem arises?

Comment: cout << "7" won't print.

Comment: It stops at the " *this = M " in the copy constructor.

Morever, I wanted to confirm that when I return something in the = operator, does it take the place of the whole " *this = M" , or just replaces M?

Comment: Please, edit your question instead of add details in comments

Comment: Add a `void Matrix::Copy( const Matrix& )` function and call it from your copy constructor/operator.

Comment: Why do you check the old values in copy constructror? Why do you delete the old memory in copy constructor? You are initializing the object.

Comment: I actually have two other constructors too in my code which are the default and parameterized constructors. And copying is like assigning, so I've to get back all the memory initially allocated to the object and assign it new memory so I can copy some other object's values into it.

Answer (score 2):

You have infinite recursion going on.  In you copy constructor you have

```
*this = M;
```

This calls your class's `operator=` which you have declared as

```
Matrix operator= (const Matrix &M)
```

You can see that you are returning by value.  When you return by value a copy is made.  To make that copy we need to call the copy construct.  This in turn calls the assignment operator again which call the copy constructor and the cycle just keeps going.

Your copy constructor can be corrected and simplified to be

```
Matrix(const Matrix & m) : rows(m.rows), columns(m.columns)
{
    ptr = new float*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        ptr[i] = new float[columns];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            ptr[i][j] = m.ptr[i][j]
}
```

Notice how I didn't have to check the state of the new class as we know what it is since we are initializing it.  Everything is uninitialized and all we have to do is initialize everything and then copy the values from the one matrix into the new one.

In regards to you assignment operator you should have it return a reference to the object instead of returning by value.  This avoids unnecessary copies and allows you to chain the operator with other operators.

Comment: I've already done all the assignment in my =operator therefore I don't need to do it in my copy constructor. Also, I've to keep the deallocation of memory in mind too(is it correct?). So could you please tell me how can I write *this = M in a better way, because I've to call the = operator as well, and avoid unwanted recursion.

Comment: @chillax You should never need to call the assignment operator in the copy constructor.  the assignment operators job is to copy one object into an already initialized object.  The copy constructors job is to copy one object into a object you are initializing.  note that `Matrix a = b;` where `b` is a `Matrix` does not befault initialize `a` and then call the assignment operator but instead it calls only the copy constructor.

Comment: I pasted your code in my copy constructor, but its not giving me the correct results. :(

I get this error 

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

Comment: @chillax My guess is you have another error in you code and fixing the copy constructor brought that up now that the code can continue.  I can assure you I have written a copy constructor like this many times and it is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks complicated to me.

I do not understand why you have chosen `float**` instead of plain `float*`. This looks better to me:

```
int rc, cc; // row count, column count
float* d; // data (rc * cc floats)
```

Memory allocation became a simpler operation:

```
d = new float[ rc * cc ];
```

Copying is also simpler:

```
memcpy( d, source.d, rc * cc * sizeof( *d ) );
```

The "hard" part is to retrieve a matrix element. You have to convert a row and column to an index:

```
index = row * column_count + column;
```

The whole class:

```
#include <iostream>

class matrix_type
{
  int rc, cc; // row count, column count
  float* d; // data

  void allocate( const int arc, const int acc ) // a prefix in arc and acc stands for Argument
  {
    if ( arc * acc == rc * cc )
      return; // nothing to do: already allocated
    delete[] d;
    rc = arc;
    cc = acc;
    d = new float[rc * cc];
  }

  void copy( const matrix_type& s )
  {
    allocate( s.rc, s.cc );
    memcpy( d, s.d, rc * cc * sizeof( *d ) );
  }

  int as_idx( const int ar, const int ac ) const
  {
    return ar * cc + ac;
  }

public:
  matrix_type( const int arc, const int acc ) : rc( 0 ), cc( 0 ), d( 0 )
  {
    allocate( arc, acc );
    memset( d, 0, rc * cc * sizeof( *d ) );
  }

  matrix_type()
  {
    delete[] d;
  }

  matrix_type( const matrix_type& s ) : rc( 0 ), cc( 0 ), d( 0 )
  {
    copy( s );
  }

  matrix_type& operator=(const matrix_type& s)
  {
    copy( s );
    return *this;
  }

  float& at( const int ar, const int ac )
  {
    if ( ar < rc && ac < cc )
      return d[as_idx( ar, ac )];
    else
      throw "out of range";
  }

  const float& at( const int ar, const int ac ) const
  {
    return const_cast<matrix_type*>(this)->at( ar, ac );
  }

  void print( std::ostream& os ) const
  {
    for ( int r = 0; r < rc; ++r )
    {
      for ( int c = 0; c < cc; ++c )
        os << at( r, c ) << ' ';
      os << '\n';
    }
  }

};

int main()
{
  matrix_type m1( 3, 5 );
  m1.at( 0, 0 ) = 1.f;
  m1.at( 2, 4 ) = 15.f;

  matrix_type m2( m1 );

  matrix_type m3( 0, 0 );
  m3 = m2;

  m3.print( std::cout );

  return 0;
}
```